# Cannot add items to a Dictionary from within the class

Tags: c#

I am working on a learning project in which I am trying to learn better practices. I have a class, `Player`, the Player among other things has `Dictionary` called `Items`, where items can be stored. The Player is initialized with just a `Name` and an `Age`, the Dictionary is supposed to be empty at the initialization of the Player.

Alongside the story, the Player can get items which will be stored in the inventory, so I am trying to create a method that can be called to do this, however I face the following issue:

If the method is not static, it cannot be called from outside the class with the following error:

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Player.AddItems(int, string)'`.

If the method is static, it does not see the `Items` Dictionar with the following error:

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Player.Items'`.

I am trying to call it from the main function (will become a class later) with:

`Player.AddItems(0, "Wallet");`.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> Items { get; set; }

        public float Damage { get; set; }

        public float Health { get; set; }

        public Player(string Name, int Age)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Age = Age;
            this.Items = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            this.Damage = 0;
            this.Health = 20;
        }

        public void AddItems(int key, string item)
        {
            this.Items.Add(key, item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Player` is a type. You need an _instance_ of said type in order to call non-static methods. E.g. `var myPlayer = new Player(...); myPlayer.AddItems(...);`.

Comment: The point of writing a Player class is that you can have more than one Player. Each instance of Player represents one distinct player, with his own Name, Age, Items, etc. So if you want to add an item to a player, you need to create a player and add items to his personal Items dictionary. If you want to look at *that* player's Items later, you'll need to keep *that* player instance, that actual object, around, in a variable, or a `List<Player>`, or something.

Comment: thanks for the explanations, no idea how I forgot that I need an object to hold that data, and not try to add items to a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Player.AddItems(int, string)'

You need to create an object first to call a non-static method of a class.

```
Player p = new Player("John", "25");
p.AddItems(1, "Data");
```

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Player.Items'.

You can't access non-static members from static methods

PS: You can assign default values to properties directly.

```
class Player
{
    public Player(string Name, int Age) : this()
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, string> Items { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public float Health { get; set; } = 20;

    public float Damage { get; set; }

    public void AddItems(int key, string item)
    {
        this.Items.Add(key, item);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the pointers, I overlooked this crucial thing, that I need to add items to the object not to the class and it's very helpful to know about being able to set default values to properties directly.

 `Player player = new Player(CharacterName, CharacterAge);`
`player.AddItems(0, "wallet");`